# MVC3 HiddenFor with Enum. Input's value is enum key not value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, enums

I have an enum:

```
public enum TaskType
{
    None = 100,
    Install = 101,
    Decommission = 102,
    Modify = 103,
    Rename = 104,
    Move = 105,
    Incident = 106,
    Other = 107
};
```

and I would like to represent its current value in my view by saving it as a property of my model:

```
public class ProvisioningListModel
{
    public TaskType TaskType { get; set; }

    public ProvisioningListModel(Task task)
    {
        TaskType = task.TaskType;
    }
}
```

My view has the corresponding:

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskType)%>
```

When the appropriate hidden input element is generated, its value is "Install" and not "101." This seemed surprising to me because an enums are usually handled by their value not their key.

```
<input id="TaskType" name="TaskType" type="hidden" value="Install">
```

Is this a common issue in MVC? Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make your enum type to inherit from int

```
public enum TaskType :int
{
  ...
```

then simply use

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(model => (int)model.TaskType)%>
```

Comment: But then I have to cast back to TaskType inside of my View and when I receive my model in my controller I have to cast again?

Comment: Any idea on why this would be from a programmatic standpoint? It would seem that an enum's key is far less useful than its value when we have to make a decision on saving one or the other. Just a bit shocked by MVC's design decision.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Enums are useful this because your enum values could vary but not keys. Even if you change your enums values you dont need to rewrite the logic.

Comment: I had to unaccept your answer because it throws an exception. You can't cast like that, at least not in MVC3 without razr syntax.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Sorry Sean I forget to warn you that you have to make your enum type to inherit from int in order to avoid cast exception.