# Enum value instead of key in hidden HiddenFor field in Razor view (Asp.Net MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I try to use this solution:

[MVC3 HiddenFor with Enum. Input's value is enum key not value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624584/mvc3-hiddenfor-with-enum-inputs-value-is-enum-key-not-value/17624648#17624648)

However it does not work in MVC5 Razor view. I get this error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

How can I get enum value in hidden field instead of enum key?

Enum type:

```
public enum LineType : int
{
    Account = 0,
    Inventory = 1,
    Service = 2
}
```

In Razor view I have:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => (int)m.LineTypeID)
```

LineTypeID is of type LineType.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Put you code in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Why do you want the `int` value? Model binding works with the text value so what is the purpose of this?

Comment: I need int value for manipulation in JavaScript. Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to change the code to work with text values.

Answer (score 11):

You can do like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LineTypeID, new {@Value = (int)Model.LineTypeID})
```

This overrides key value

Comment: It worked for me, except that I had to do (int)Model.LineTypeID instead of m.

Answer (score 0):

Just to further detail the answer here:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => (int)m.LineTypeID)
```

This will not work. You cannot cast on the template. When you cast it creates a new variable and this will not work.

Remove the cast to int and add the @value field as described.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LineTypeID, new {@Value = (int)m.LineTypeID, id = "LineTypeID"})
```

I like to add the Id field so I can later easily access the value in JavaScript:

```
var lineTypeIDValue = parseInt($("#LineTypeID").val());
```

Also in C# you do not need to add a type to your enum.

```
public enum LineType
{
    Account = 0,
    Inventory = 1,
    Service = 2
}
```

You should now

Comment: You do not need to manually set the id parameter. MVC does it automatically for you corresponding to the property name.

Comment: Sometimes setting the Id is beneficial when you start working with Javascript. In some cases, lets say your naming conventions for c# are different. 

An example of this is lower and upper casing the first letter of a variable or class. Lets say standard convention with the backed you are using follow MyHiddenForVariable, but in javascript, the convention is using myHiddenForVariable. By using Id assignment, you can ensure you have matching naming conventions. This is great when you are working with existing code that may have variances in naming convention between back-end and front-end.

Comment: Yes you're right. Until today I'm using the C# naming of the objects because when referring to in JavaScript I'm using MVC Helper Html.IdFor(model => model.MyProperty)